# how to calculate the average of training accuracy in Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

i am trying to calculate the average of the training accuracy in y model which is written with KERAS, i have 200 epochs. So in the end i want to sum each training accuracy in each epoch with the previous one and divided them by 200..

here is my code

```
num = 200
total_sum = 0
for n in range(num):
    avg_train=np.array(model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=64, verbose=2))
    total_sum = avg_train + total_sum
avg = total_sum/num

score=model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print(score)
print('the average is',avg)
```

i am trying to store each accuracy in a numpy array to be able using it in the summation operation but it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Master Implementation\MLPADAM.py", line 87, in <module>
    total_sum = avg_train + total_sum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'History' and 'int'
```

Comment: `np.model.evaluate`??? Plus, your code will fit 200 epochs 200 times (`num`), which I guess is not what you want exactly...

Comment: np.model , i have edit it ,,  and num=200 because i used it in a for loop with 200 iteration

Comment: As is, it will run a 200 iteration loop, with each iteration being 200 epochs (i.e. 40,000 epochs total). Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: no.. i want only to calculate the training accuracy of the 200 epochs

Comment: I thought so... see answer (and forget the loop!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several issues with your question...

To start with, your code will fit a model with 200 epochs 200 times, i.e. a total of 200*200 = 40,000 epochs.

Moreover, since `model.fit` in Keras is run incrementally, each call of `model.fit` in your loop will continue training from where the previous iteration stopped, so effectively at the end you will indeed have a model fitted with 40,000 epochs.

**Assuming** that this is not what you are trying to do, but you want simply the average accuracy during your training, the answer is to use the `History` object returned by `model.fit`; from the [`model.fit` docs](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> **Returns**
>
> A `History` object. Its `History.history` attribute is a record of training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well as validation loss values and validation metrics values (if applicable).

So, here is a quick demonstration with MNIST and only 5 epochs (and forget the for loop!):

```
# your model definition
# your model.compile()

batch_size = 128
epochs = 5

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=epochs,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(x_test, y_test)  # optional
      )

# output
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 76s - loss: 0.3367 - acc: 0.8974 - val_loss: 0.0765 - val_acc: 0.9742
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 0.1164 - acc: 0.9656 - val_loss: 0.0516 - val_acc: 0.9835
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 74s - loss: 0.0866 - acc: 0.9741 - val_loss: 0.0411 - val_acc: 0.9863
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 0.0730 - acc: 0.9781 - val_loss: 0.0376 - val_acc: 0.9871
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 0.0639 - acc: 0.9810 - val_loss: 0.0354 - val_acc: 0.9881
```

`hist.history` is a dictionary containing the value of the metrics for each epoch:

```
hist.history
# result:
{'acc': [0.8973833333969117,
  0.9656000000635783,
  0.9740500000317891,
  0.9780500000635783,
  0.9810333334604899],
 'loss': [0.3367467244784037,
  0.11638248273332914,
  0.08664042545557023,
  0.07301943883101146,
  0.06391783343354861],
 'val_acc': [0.9742, 0.9835, 0.9863, 0.9871, 0.9881],
 'val_loss': [0.07650674062222243,
  0.051606363496184346,
  0.04107686730045825,
  0.03761903735231608,
  0.03537947320453823]}
```

To get the training accuracy per epoch:

```
hist.history['acc']
# result:
[0.8973833333969117,
 0.9656000000635783,
 0.9740500000317891,
 0.9780500000635783,
 0.9810333334604899]
```

and the average value is simply

```
np.mean(hist.history['acc']) # numpy assumed imported as np
# 0.9592233334032695
```

Comment: when trying your code on 5 epochs like you on my model it gives me the following warning : method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update

Comment: @HadeerEl-Zayat That is just a warning (not error), irrelevant to your question. It is probably due to the small no. of epochs (see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5008)), and it should appear with your own code, too, for `epochs=5`. Setting `epochs=200` may clear it...

Comment: i set the epochs to 5 like u but i set the verbose = 2 it run without the warning

Comment: @HadeerEl-Zayat so, did the answer resolve your issue??

Comment: @desertnaut, did you mean that keras computes accuracy of each epoch as average of all batches or not?

Comment: @honar.cs actually did not touch this detail, but yes

Comment: @desertnaut, I want to do identical process in tensorflow not keras, if I sum the accuracy of each mini-batch and at last of this epoch take the average to the accuracy for this epoch, and for loss the same thing? I am right or not?